php scrape data and no response due to long waiting
I am writing a php to scrape data from internet. It works smoothly and now I want to go one step furhter. After scraping the name and the url of the source, I want to go to each link and scrape the content of each link separately (which is the most important part of my project). For example, if there are 100 links in the source, then I need to visit each link separately and scrape their information (of course all the information are different). Here is my php file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>     
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>contacts.php</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
                    
        
        $tz = 'Asia/Hong_Kong';
        $timestamp = time();
        $dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz)); //first argument "must" be a string
        $dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
        

        $final_name = ""; $final_url = "";
        $chin_gov_html = 'https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/wr/' . substr($dt->format('Y/m/d'),0, 4) . substr($dt->format('Y/m/d'),5, 2) . '/'. substr($dt->format('Y/m/d'),8, 2) . 'c.htm';

        
        $rootFolder = dirname(__DIR__);
        require $rootFolder.'/Bulletin Translator/private/lib/vendor/autoload.php';

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle');

        // Send an asynchronous request.

        $array_string = "";

        $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $chin_gov_html);
        $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response)
        {
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $body = (string) $response->getBody();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $doc->loadHTML($body);
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
            

            $bulltin_name = $xpath->evaluate('//body/div/div/div/ul/li/a'); 
            
            $counter = 0; 
            foreach($bulltin_name as $element)
            {
                $purified_bulletin_name = "";
                $bulletin_name = $element->textContent;
                
                for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($bulletin_name); $a++)
                {
                    if (substr($bulletin_name, $a, 1) != " ")
                    {
                        $purified_bulletin_name .= substr($bulletin_name, $a, 1);
                    }
                }
                
                $bulletin_number = strval(mb_substr($purified_bulletin_name, 4, 3, 'UTF-8'));
                $purified_bulletin_name = explode("-", $purified_bulletin_name)[1];
                $bulletin_url = "https://www.info.gov.hk" . $element->getAttribute('href');
                
                               
                // Scrape Bulletin Time

                $rootFolder = dirname(__DIR__);
                require $rootFolder.'/Bulletin Translator/private/lib/vendor/autoload.php';

                $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
                $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle');

                // Send an asynchronous request.
                $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $bulletin_url);
                $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response)
                {
                    $doc = new DOMDocument();
                    $body = (string) $response->getBody();
                    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                    $doc->loadHTML($body);
                    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
                    

                    $bulltin_time = $xpath->evaluate('//body/div/span/div');
                    foreach($bulltin_time as $element)
                    {
                        $bulletin_time = $element->textContent;
                        print_r($bulletin_time . "<br>");
                    }
                });
                $promise->wait();
            }
        });
        
        $promise->wait();
        
    ?>

</body>
</html>

I try to add one more similar scraping code inside an async function but it returns an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client
error: GET https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle resulted in a
403 rate limit exceeded response: {"message":"API rate limit
exceeded for 112.118.4.218. (But here's the good news: Authenticated
requests get a higher ra (truncated...)

to me. Is it forbidden or just something I go wrong?

Read the error message. Read it again. API rate limit exceeded for... (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher ra -- Free/unauthenticated accounts only get so many requests per time period, and you've gone over it. Slow it down or create an account.

Always read the documentation

How to slow it down?

Generally unrelated to problem, but you appear to be building this as a web page, and I think this would be better off as a CLI application. Also, if you are doing scraping at any scale of consequence I'd also recommend looking at using a queue system with workers that "checkout" links to scrape.

sleep() can work, but  just know that your webpage will be really slow

Wait... why are you using Guzzle to access the GitHub repo for Guzzle?

@ aynber, where should I put the sleep() function?
